# Make a div background-image responsive and its content too

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to recreate Minecraft's experience bar in HTML, so far I managed to get the background responsive but I can't get the "covering" bar working. When I make it min-height: 100% instead of 15px it is not shown at all.

```
.xpbar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 15px; /* works */
  /* min-height: 100%; doesn't work */
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/4esnIWF.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/zLwds/2/

Re-size the window to see the issue!

**TL;DR How can I make the second image responsive too?**

Comment: So only Minecraft users should know what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained. It's like a progress bar, the background + the foreground with a % width!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Is that what you were trying to achieve?

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zLwds/3/)

Comment: Thank you! I would have preferred the cover bar to re-size like the background bar (keeping ratio) but it still works.

Comment: Strange - ratio seems fine when i try it here in Safari.

Comment: Is it already rendered cropped or is that your screenshot? Which FF version is that?

Comment: Yes I cropped it sorry, it was just to show that the left side has wider cells that the right side! But your solution still works.